# Is $2^e$ irrational or rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Please help me with the following question.

> Prove or disprove that $2^e$ is an irrational number, where $e$ is the Neipper number.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never seen this spelling but Napier or Neper.

Comment: Me neither. It took me a while to realize that $e$ was supposed to be the mathematical constant $e$, which everybody means when writing $e$. "Neipper number" is very confusing, to say the least.

Comment: According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalNumber.html) this is an open problem.

Comment: Are you sure? It could be that the open problem is actually the transcendance and not the irrationality. I don't know however the truth about this question.

Answer (score 2):

Determining whether $2^e$ is irrational or not is an open problem. And more generally, the task of determining whether $(\text{rational})^{\text{irrational}}$ is rational or not appears to be extremely difficult.

Answer (score -1):

**Read the comments to know more**

just two lines:
(its all i could think and write)

let $$2^e=p$$
taking log of base 2 both sides

$$\log_22^e=\log_2p\implies e=\log_2p$$
and lets say that e is irrational

now assuming that $\log_2p=\frac ab, b\in N-\{1\}$ where $a$ is an irrational number and $N$is the set of all natural numbers and $2^a\ne n^mb$ where $ m$ being non-zero positive integers

so $$\log_2p=\frac ab\implies\log_2p^b=a\implies p^b=2^a\implies p=(2^a)^{\frac 1b}\ldots (1)$$

so from (1) it is clear that $p$ is always an irrational and from the very first statement we can say that a number power to an irrational number is an irrational number

Comment: $e$ is the famous Euler constant, which is known to be irrational. It's not very clear how this answer is useful in view of the question. How do you conclude from this answer that $2^e$ is irrational?

Comment: because $p=(2^a)^{\frac 1b}$ is an irrational number and $p=2^e$

Comment: Wait a second, how does this work? How is $p=2^{a/b}=2^e$. $a/b$ is rational, and $e$ is not.

Comment: read the answer, $a$ is taken as an irrational number and hence $a/b$ is also an irrational number and i have let the value of $2^e$ as $p$ so $p$ is a symbol which represent the value of $2^e$

Comment: So basically you're saying that  $2^a$ is always irrational if $a$ is irrational? That would make the entire question trivial, and I'm not so sure that that is true.

Comment: well even if $2^a$ would be an rational number then $1/b$ will make it irrational number so we need not to consider here about $2^a$ being rational or not

Comment: When you say "now assuming that $\log_2 p = \frac a b$", this is tantamount to saying, "let's assume $e$ is rational".

Comment: $a$ is taken as an irrational number and $b$ is an integer and we know that irrational divided by rational is irrational hence $a/b$ is IRRATIONAL  and so $\log_2 p$ is IRRATIONAL and $\log_2 p=e$ so $e$ is IRRATIONAL

Comment: @Asterrovels Okay, but in that case, since $a$ is irrational you can no longer claim that $(2^a)^{\frac 1 b}$ is irrational.

Comment: how? can you tell me please?

Comment: Basically your reasoning is that $2^a$ is always irrational if $a$ is irrational. This isn't a trivial assumption, and it needs to be proven. If we assume that this assumption isn't correct, then $(2^a)^{1/b}$ need not be irrational. Let's just say, for example, that $2^a=9$ for some irrational $a$, and $b=2$, then we get that $(2^a)^{1/b}=3$ which is obviously rational. These numbers were just made up, and are of course not close to $2^e$, but do you see the problem I'm having with following your reasoning?

Comment: @Asterrovels If $a$ is irrational then $2^a$ can be rational. In fact, for most rationals $x$, $\log_2(x)$ is an irrational number. For instance, you can easily prove by contradiction that $\log_2(3)$ is irrational, since if it wasn't you'd end up with a power of two being equal to a power of three.

Comment: @Scounged that's correct then i must make other assumption that $2^a\ne n^{mb}$ where $ m$ being non-zero positive integers

Comment: Yeah, something needs to change I believe. But I don't know how to prove that $2^e$ is irrational. If what is said in the comments to the question is true, this will indeed be a very difficult problem to solve.